Is there a term for a tree representing a hierarchy of subset relations?
Consider a collection of $N$ sets $S = \{S_1, \cdots, S_N\}$ where $S_i \subset A$. We can represent the relations between the subsets by building a tree. We make the root of the tree a node representing $A$, then $S_i$ is the child of $S_j$ if $S_i$ is the largest subset of $S_j$.
Is there a name for this or something similar to this? The procedure above is a bit ambiguous as a node could have multiple options for its parent (e.g., should the node $23$ have $123$ or $234$ as a parent).
However, it seems like something like this would exist. It seems related to inclusion order, but I can't find much about that term.

Would it be a DAG (directed acyclic graph) not a tree?

@DanielV Yes, if you connect all options for the parents, but if you pick one, it should be a tree.

In general, there will be no single largest subset of $S_j$. Nor is there a name for the resulting (directed!) graph. But the relation you describe—precisely which pairs of your vertices have arcs (directed edges)—is called the cover relation. We say that $y$ covers $x$ to mean that

$x$ and $y$ are distinct,
$x$ is related to $y$, and
there is no $z$ distinct from $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ is related to $z$ and $z$ is related to $y$.

So it would be very reasonable to call the digraph the “cover graph” (with respect to the $\subseteq$ relation). Note, however, that this reasonableness is from the perspective of order theory—we’re dealing with the partial order $\subseteq$. But if our context shifts from order theory to graph theory, then we need to be a bit cautious since cover has a different meaning to graph theorists.
Note that given any partially ordered set $P = (X, \leq$), the cover relation $<\!\!\cdot$ with respect to $\leq$ is precisely its transitive reduction. That fact allows us to draw the digraph $P$ using undirected edges (and only the edges of $<\!\!\cdot$) by simply ensuring that for any distinct $x,y\in X$, if $x \leq y$ we put $y$ somewhere higher on the page than $x$. If we take that approach, then $\leq$ amounts to the reachability relation for $(X, <\!\!\cdot)$. And we call any such drawing a Hasse diagram of $P$. Typically, we don’t care to distinguish among the infinitely many such drawings of $P$ that are possible, and in those cases we refer (in a slight abuse of terminology) to it/them as the Hasse diagram of $P$.

You can get something unambiguous by replacing "largest" with "maximal." This is a construction called the Hasse diagram of a poset. It's not a tree in general, already for the full powerset of a $2$-element set, but it is a directed acyclic graph.
